# Unable to resize HTML Table row with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, row

I have a simple table with rows inside, and I try to force the height of a row.

```js
document.getElementById('myrow').height='300px';
```

```html
<table style='border:1px solid black;'>
 <tr id='myrow'><td>Hello world (should be dynamically increased)</td></tr>
</table>
 

<table style='border:1px solid black;'>
 <tr height=300><td>Hello world from second table (static size)</td></tr>
</table>
```

However my javascript does not seem to have any effect on the row height. How can I force it ?

Comment: The height attribute has been deprecated for at least 15 years, probably longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use style before the height property.

For example:

```
document.getElementById("myrow").style.height = '300px';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using style.height like this:

```js
document.getElementById("myrow").style.height = '300px';
```